# TFS 2015 Gated Checkin issues

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, tfs-2015, gated-checkin

I know it's a very new feature but I was wondering if anyone has had any success with the new gated check-in mechanism in TFS 2015 Update 2?

We've copied our TFS 2013 and upgraded it to 2015 then applied to update 2.  I've created a build server, installed VS 2015 on it and the TFS build agent software - everything seems to work up to this point.

I created a build definition for an existing project which would build fine on my dev. box but running the build gave errors - due to missing files on the build box.  I updated the nuget packages to ensure a good build and tried another check-in - same result as before (huh?).

Checking the source on the build box, it did not include the changes I'd made, it was as if the shelfset had not been applied.

Creating another build for a different project, the gated check-in dialog could not decide the correct build to run - leaving it for the developer to choose (not necessary under the old system).  Additionally, the changes listed as associated with that build were actually for another, unrelated project.

Anyone out there actually getting this stuff to work with an existing repository?  Your thoughts and comments would be appreciated before I waste another day on this.

Answer (score 0):

- changes not included: did you check the Clean option from Repository tab?

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/define/repository#GitHubOtheroptions):

> •Set this to false if you want to define an incremental build to
>   improve performance.
>
> Tip: In this case, if you are building Visual Studio projects, on the
>   Build tab, you can also uncheck the Clean check box of the Visual
>   Studio Build or MSBuild step.

- gated check-in build undecided: check what filters are defined in these two build definitions [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/define/triggers#TFVCgatedcheck_in)

Comment: Yep, checked that option - and pretty much every other option as I worked my way through the various permutations.  Doesn't seem to matter if the work area is dirty or clean.  The shelf-set gets created, that I know, but it just doesn't seem to be applied to the checked out source.  Put a call into MS, waiting to hear back.